# Verify commitment C commits to the same value that E encrypts

Tags: public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

Given the following (using additive notation):

- $G$ - generator of an elliptic curve group of order $q$
- $s$ - secret drawn uniformly from the distribution $1..q$
- $k$ and $K$ - a private public keypair
- $E$ - an encryption of $s$ under $K$
- $C$ - a commitment to $s$ such that $C = sG$.

Note that it's important that $C$ is formed as $sG$ - though pointers to general literature using any kind of commitments that satisfy the below problem would be appreciated as well.

How can I produce $E$ in such a way that, given $E$, $C$, and $K$, (and some other normal public info like generators, etc) one can verify that $C$ commits to the value that $E$ encrypts?

Comment: Thank you @kelalaka for the formatting.

Comment: You have to do calculations with encrypted data. So the encryption function must be homomorphic in some sense. It means that it is necessary to specify the $E(K,s).$

Comment: As written, with the commitment and a guess to the secret, you can verify the secret.  This is not true of standard commitment schemes - is that an intended feature of what you're looking for?

Comment: @poncho I've revised the question to be more clear. By "a guess to the secret" do you mean a random guess as in a brute force? I looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme for my usage of commitment. If I'm using the terminology incorrectly by all means point me to a place to be more informed.

Comment: Your commitment scheme (which *is* a commitment scheme) has computational hiding instead of the more classical "perfect hiding". I.e., a classical Pedersen commitment has $C=sG+rH$, with the additional $rH$ term to perfectly randomize the commitment. That's what poncho is after.

Comment: @RubenDeSmet: actually, his scheme $sG$ is not hiding at all; if someone has a guess to $s$, they can verify it.  Hiding means that it is infeasible to gain any information about the secret, including 'is the secret this specific value?'

Comment: Yes, fair point. I am assuming a uniform distribution for $s$, which would make for a computationally hiding/perfectly binding scheme.

Comment: I will specify in the question that $s$ is a uniform distribution as that was my intention. Thank you @poncho for pointing the deficiency and Ruben De Smet for pointing out what the implicit assumption.